# How to remove message output for the WP-PostRatings Plugin?

Tags: plugins, plugin-wp-postratings

When the user clicks on the *vote* image, the image changes to the *voted* state. If the user clicks the image in the *voted* state again, a message pops up saying:

> You Had Already Rated This Post. Post ID #X

I want it so that this message does not pop up and the 'voted' image stays as is.

Below is what I believe to be the relevant code needed to make this change. It is from lines 558-633 of *wp-postratings.php*. If someone can take a look and let me know what I need to change, I'd be very grateful.

```
### Function: Process Ratings
process_ratings();
function process_ratings() {
    global $wpdb, $user_identity, $user_ID;
    $rate = intval($_GET['rate']);
    $post_id = intval($_GET['pid']);
    if($rate > 0 && $post_id > 0 && check_allowtorate()) {      
        // Check For Bot
        $bots_useragent = array('googlebot', 'google', 'msnbot', 'ia_archiver', 'lycos', 'jeeves', 'scooter', 'fast-webcrawler', 'slurp@inktomi', 'turnitinbot', 'technorati', 'yahoo', 'findexa', 'findlinks', 'gaisbo', 'zyborg', 'surveybot', 'bloglines', 'blogsearch', 'ubsub', 'syndic8', 'userland', 'gigabot', 'become.com');
        $useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
        foreach ($bots_useragent as $bot) { 
            if (stristr($useragent, $bot) !== false) {
                return;
            } 
        }
        header('Content-Type: text/html; charset='.get_option('blog_charset').'');
        postratings_textdomain();
        $rated = check_rated($post_id);
        // Check Whether Post Has Been Rated By User
        if(!$rated) {
            // Check Whether Is There A Valid Post
            $post = get_post($post_id);
            // If Valid Post Then We Rate It
            if($post && !wp_is_post_revision($post)) {
                $ratings_max = intval(get_option('postratings_max'));
                $ratings_custom = intval(get_option('postratings_customrating'));
                $ratings_value = get_option('postratings_ratingsvalue');
                $post_title = addslashes($post->post_title);
                $post_ratings = get_post_custom($post_id);
                $post_ratings_users = intval($post_ratings['ratings_users'][0]);
                $post_ratings_score = intval($post_ratings['ratings_score'][0]);    
                // Check For Ratings Lesser Than 1 And Greater Than $ratings_max
                if($rate < 1 || $rate > $ratings_max) {
                    $rate = 0;
                }
                $post_ratings_users = ($post_ratings_users+1);
                $post_ratings_score = ($post_ratings_score+intval($ratings_value[$rate-1]));
                $post_ratings_average = round($post_ratings_score/$post_ratings_users, 2);
                if (!update_post_meta($post_id, 'ratings_users', $post_ratings_users)) {
                    add_post_meta($post_id, 'ratings_users', $post_ratings_users, true);
                }
                if(!update_post_meta($post_id, 'ratings_score', $post_ratings_score)) {
                    add_post_meta($post_id, 'ratings_score', $post_ratings_score, true);
                }
                if(!update_post_meta($post_id, 'ratings_average', $post_ratings_average)) {
                    add_post_meta($post_id, 'ratings_average', $post_ratings_average, true);    
                }
                // Add Log
                if(!empty($user_identity)) {
                    $rate_user = addslashes($user_identity);
                } elseif(!empty($_COOKIE['comment_author_'.COOKIEHASH])) {
                    $rate_user = addslashes($_COOKIE['comment_author_'.COOKIEHASH]);
                } else {
                    $rate_user = __('Guest', 'wp-postratings');
                }
                $rate_userid = intval($user_ID);
                // Only Create Cookie If User Choose Logging Method 1 Or 3
                $postratings_logging_method = intval(get_option('postratings_logging_method'));
                if($postratings_logging_method == 1 || $postratings_logging_method == 3) {
                    $rate_cookie = setcookie("rated_".$post_id, $ratings_value[$rate-1], time() + 30000000, COOKIEPATH);
                }
                // Log Ratings No Matter What
                $rate_log = $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO $wpdb->ratings VALUES (0, $post_id, '$post_title', ".$ratings_value[$rate-1].",'".current_time('timestamp')."', '".get_ipaddress()."', '".@gethostbyaddr(get_ipaddress())."' ,'$rate_user', $rate_userid)");
                // Output AJAX Result
                echo the_ratings_results($post_id, $post_ratings_users, $post_ratings_score, $post_ratings_average);
                exit();
            } else {
                printf(__('Invalid Post ID. Post ID #%s.', 'wp-postratings'), $post_id);
                exit();
            } // End if($post)
        } else {
            printf(__('You Had Already Rated This Post. Post ID #%s.', 'wp-postratings'), $post_id);
            exit(); 
        }// End if(!$rated)
    } // End if($rate && $post_id && check_allowtorate())
}
```

---

*EDIT: You can find the Plugin [here](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-postratings/)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just comment out (or change) the following line:

```
// printf(__('You Had Already Rated This Post. Post ID #%s.', 'wp-postratings'), $post_id);
```

If you just want to not have the `$post_id`, change the line to the following:

```
_e('You Had Already Rated This Post. Post ID #%s.', 'wp-postratings');
```

**Btw: If you change a plugin and then make an update, all your changes are gone.**

Comment: Strangely enough, I was sure this was working when I tested it yesterday (which was why I gave you the check mark) but now it's behaving strangely (ratings score isn't showing). I tried editing the line to look like this... `printf (__("<img src='http://site.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-postratings/images/site/rating_1_on.png' />", 'wp-postratings'), $post_ratings_score);` to get the rating score to show up but it's not working. Any ideas? By the way, that img url is the 'voted' image.

Comment: Take a look at `printf` via google. It fills placeholders like `%1$s` or `%s`. If you haven't got placeholders, you don't need it.

Comment: I took a look but it seems what I need to insert in there is `$post_ratings_score` to output the amount of votes? Is there any way to insert `$post_ratings_score` in that line two posts above? Or maybe just disable the voting function (make the image unclickable) after a user has voted?

Comment: Please, read my comment extremly careful - again. It is the answer. Hint: "placeholders". Another hint: Compare the both lines in the answer after reading about printf in php.net.